# How to create link in NFS that is visible through NTFS?

Tags: ntfs, nfs

I have a NFS share in Windows 2008 mounted in Linux.

If i create a symlink in Linux it works as expected in Linux.
In Windows it appears as a file and we can't follow it.

If i create a link in Windows with mklink (`mklink /D directory target`) it's visible as a link in Windows and as a normal directory in Linux. This is OK.

The problem is that i want to create the links in the Linux side and make them work on both sides.

Comment: Try install Services for Network File System role on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Already installed.I can access the files, just can't create directory links that work in Windows.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to your problem?